# Loading a select list in angular 2 based on data entered by user in form

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

So I have a form in which I am getting some user input. Based on this input I am fetching data from server. I need to display this data in a drop down select list. However my select list is always empty even though I can see I am receiving data from the server.

I have attached my html code:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form >
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
              <label for="name">Enter name of the new concept:</label>
              <input type="text" #conceptName>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label for="test">Select test:</label>
                <select #testName id="testName" (change)="fetchAllBuckets(testName.value)">
                  <option *ngFor="let test of tests"  ><a>{{test.testName}}</a></option>
                </select>
              </div>
           </div>


            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <label for="test">Select bucket:</label>
               <select #bucketName name="allBuckets" [(ngModel)]="buckets">
                <option *ngFor="let bucket of buckets"  ><a>{{bucket.testName}}</a></option>
              </select>
            </div>



       <div class="col-xs-12">
         <button class="btn btn-success" 
         type="submit" 
         (click)="addNewConcept(testName.value,bucketName.value,conceptName.value)">Add</button>
         <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Delete</button>
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Clear</button>
       </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { databaseService } from '../../services/database.service';
import { Test } from '../test/test.module';
import { Bucket } from '../bucket/bucket.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-concept',
  templateUrl: './concept.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./concept.component.css']
})
export class ConceptComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild("testName")testName:ElementRef;
  constructor(private databaseservice:databaseService) { }
  tests:Test[];
  buckets:Bucket[];
  testSelected=true;
  testText="";
  ngOnInit() {
    this.databaseservice.getTests().subscribe(
      (response)=>{
        this.tests=response.json();
      }
    )
  }

  fetchAllBuckets(testName:string)
  {

    this.testText="hello";

    this.databaseservice.getBuckets(testName).subscribe(
      (response)=>{
        this.buckets=response.json();
        console.log(this.buckets);
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
    this.testSelected=false;
  }
  addNewConcept(testName,bucketName,conceptName)
  {
    console.log(testName+" "+bucketName+" "+conceptName);
    this.databaseservice.addConcept("'"+testName+"'","'"+bucketName+"'","'"+conceptName+"'").subscribe(
      (response)=>console.log(response),
      (error)=>console.log(error)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have bind null array to for loop, this is not  allowed in angular. opens of your browser， see what errors occured.